# Audiokit mic input not working on IPad Pro

Tags: audiokit

Any suggestions on why the Audiokit mic input would work fine on IPad Mini 2 but not at all on 3rd gen IPad Pro? Have tried the obvious: confirmed my app allows mic in pro settings, mic is working using voice notes app on pro. Both devices are latest IOS version and Audiokit is latest release 4.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app processes some audio input with no output needed. The IPad mini didn't care that there was no output module in the chain, the IPad pro did so I added the line "AudioKit.output = silence" to the end of the audio chain. This fixed the problem.